# Add field if not exist to document in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

**Source Doc**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "12345", 
    "LastName" : "Smith", 
    "FirstName" : "Fred", 
    "ProfileCreated" : NumberLong(1447118831860), 
    "DropOut" : false, 
}
```

**New Doc**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "12345", 
    "LastName" : "Smith", 
    "FirstName" : "Fred", 
    "ProfileCreated" : NumberLong(1447118831860), 
    "DropOut" : true, 
    "LatestConsultation" : false,
}
```

I have two collections which share a lot of the same document ID's and fields but over time the new documents will have fields added to them and or completely new documents with new ID's will get created.

I think I know how to handle new documents using `$setOnInsert` and `upsert = true` but I'm not sure how best to handle the addition of new fields. The behavior I require for documents that exists in both collection matched on `_id` with new fields is to add the new field to the document without modifying the values of any of the other fields even if they have changed as in the example where the `DropOut` value has changed. The resulting document I require is.

**Result document**

```
{ 
    "_id" : "12345", 
    "LastName" : "Smith", 
    "FirstName" : "Fred", 
    "ProfileCreated" : NumberLong(1447118831860), 
    "DropOut" : false, 
    "LatestConsultation" : false,
}
```

---

What is the best and most performatic way to achive this? Also if this can somehow be combined into a single statement that also includes the addition of documents that exists in the new collection but not in the source collection that would be amazing :-)

PS. I am using Pymongo so a Pymongo example would be even better but I can translate a mongo shell example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is this is possible with an atomic update. However, you could string in some mixed operations and tackle this in such a way that you iterate the new collection and for each document in the new collection:

- Use the `_id` field to query the old collection. Use the `findOne()` method to return a document from the old collection that matches on the `_id` from the new collection.
- Extend the new doc with the old doc by adding the new fields which do not exist in the old document.
- Update the new collection with this merged document.

---

The following basic mongo shell example demonstrates the algorithm above:

```
function merge(from, to) {
    var obj = {};
    if (!from) {
        from = {};
    } else {
        obj = from; 
    }
    for (var key in to) {
        if (!from.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = to[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

db.new_collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc){
    var old_doc = db.old_collection.findOne({ "_id": doc._id }),
        merged_doc = merge(old_doc, doc);

    db.new_collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": merged_doc }
    );
});
```

---

For dealing with large collections, better leverage your updates using the bulk API which offers better performance and efficient update operations done through 
sending the update requests in bulk rather than each update operation for every request (which is slow). The method to use is the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** function, which can be applied in the above example as:

```
function merge(from, to) {
    var obj = {};
    if (!from) {
        from = {};
    } else {
        obj = from; 
    }
    for (var key in to) {
        if (!from.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = to[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

var ops = [];
db.new_collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc){
    var old_doc = db.old_collection.findOne({ "_id": doc._id }),
        merged_doc = merge(old_doc, doc);

    ops.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": merged_doc }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 1000) {
        db.new_collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});

if (ops.length > 0)  db.new_collection.bulkWrite(ops);
```

Or for MongoDB `2.6.x` and `3.0.x` releases use this version of **[`Bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** operations:

```
var bulk = db.new_collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

db.new_collection.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc){
    var old_doc = db.old_collection.findOne({ "_id": doc._id }),
        merged_doc = merge(old_doc, doc);

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ "$set": merged_doc });

    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.new_collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 1000 !== 0 )  bulk.execute();
```

The Bulk operations API in both cases will help reduce the IO load on the server by sending the requests only once in every 1000 documents in the collection to process.